# How to install ansible using ansible and pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ansible

Hi I'm trying to install ansible with pip using vagrant and ansible in a ubuntu server Trusty64. I used roles to install python3 and in the role to install ansible is:

```
---
# tasks file for roles/ansible
- name: install pip3
  apt: name=python3-pip state=present
  tags: ansible

- name: install librerias dev
  apt: name=libssl-dev state=present
  tags: ansible

- name: install librerias essential
  apt: name=build-essential state=present
  tags: ansible

- name: install librerias libdev
  apt: name=libffi-dev state=present
  tags: ansible

- name: install librerias pydev
  apt: name=python-dev state=present
  tags: ansible

- name: install librerias pydev
  apt: upgrade=yes
  tags: ansible

- name: install setuptools
  command: pip3 install setuptools
  tags: ansible

- name: upgrade setuptools
  command: pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
  tags: ansible

- name: install ansible
  command: pip3 install ansible
  tags: ansible
```

After python3 is installed and pip3 the installation fails installing ansible with the next error traceback:

```
Python 3.5 or later is required",                                                                   
    "stderr_lines": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):", 
        "  File \"/usr/bin/pip3\", line 5, in <module>", 
        "    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point", 
        "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py\", line 93, in <module>", 
        "    raise RuntimeError(\"Python 3.5 or later is required\")", 
        "RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required"
    ], 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
```

And I cannot see why should I too to solve this because I already have installed python3 using this role:

```
---
# tasks file for roles/python3

- name: aniadir repositorio
  apt_repository: 
   repo: ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
   state: present

- name: actualizar cache
  apt: update_cache=yes

- name: instalar python3
  apt: name=python3.7 state=present
```

and I already used pip3 to install setuptools and to upgrade it. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu), you need to add:

```
- name: Select python3.7 as default python3
  alternatives:
    name: python3
    path: /usr/bin/python3.7
```

As you can see in the error, Ansible tries to install Ansible with Python 3.4:

`/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py`

Python 3.4 is the default Python 3 for your installation. Installing Python 3.7 only installs `python3.7` but does not make it the default Python 3. To do this, you must explicitly tell the system to use `python3.7` when calling `python3`, using the [alternatives system](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/alternatives_module.html).